# Intent and lambda and need to clean before every run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lambda

I have an annoying problem that forces me to *Build -> Clean Project* before every attempt to run it. But it's not obvious (at least for me) as to what's causing it.

#### Description

1. I First run the app - it runs fine;
2. Find something that needs to be changed;
3. Code such change;
4. Click run - (it doesn't matter if it's *run* or *close and run*);
5. App is launched normally;
6. Can fill in EditText just fine;
7. Tap button to login: crash.

**Important:** (*possible narrowing down the problem*) As you'll se below, I have a code that calls another activity. When I remove the code that creates the intent and calls it, the app runs fine, and when I add it again, it sometimes runs fine for a few more attempts, going back to the problem later.

---

#### The error:

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.foobar.activity.FooActivity cannot be cast to com.example.foobar.activity.BarActivity
>                      at com.example.foobar.activity.-$Lambda$3.$m$0(Unknown Source)
>                      at com.example.foobar.activity.-$Lambda$3.onClick(Unknown Source)
>                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
> ```

---

#### Code

**FooActivity.java**:

```
Button btLogin;
void onCreate(..){ prepareComponents(); }
void prepareComponents(){
    // findViewById
    btLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> onClickLogin());
}

void onClickLogin(){
    // check user info and do other apparently unimportant stuff
    Intent intent = new Intent(FooActivity.this, BarActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

---

#### Setup

- Android Studio 2.3.3
- Gradle 3.3
- buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
- compileSdkVersion 25
- Using buildTypes
- Using some libs in gradlde
- Using `jackOptions enabled` in gradle

My Top-level gradle shows `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`.

---

#### Complementary info:

- *Instant run* is already disabled.
- I tried checking *workd offline*.
- *Invalidate Caches / Restart* just moves to problem to another part of code, but same behavior. Update: problem's gone gack to first screen.
- Tested on 2 different devices with different android versions.
- Uninstalling the app from the device doesn't help - I still need to clean project.
- Running without cleaning takes less time in *process running* "Gradle Build Running", but when I clean (which itself isn't very time consuming), the next run takes 1m30s to "Gradle Build Run".
- I've tried google, but the closest I could find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415476/jack-and-android-lambda-runtime-failure-until-clean-build), which seems to be the same, but didn't really help me.

---

From my tests, commenting out the intent and activity call part *solves* the problem, by I need to call it, so not really. Besides, it works after cleaning, so it doesn't seem like an actual code problem. What could it be and how could I solve it?

<sub>I don't know what else info to include. Just let me know :)</sub>